# gud-pdb emacs usage and PATH

Tags: python, emacs, environment-variables, pdb

I'm trying to use *gud-pdb* for Python debugging within Emacs.

Having an issue that pdb doesn't seem to be searching the `PATH` when looking for my `.py` files

I.e., I have a python script in a dir which is on the `PATH`, I can run this script from anywhere outside of `pdb`, i.e., from the command line.

But when I try and run it from within `pdb` it tells me the file doesn't exist.

I'm trying to run `pdb` against the script in a dir that contains the data to be processed.

I think this is a standard thing to want to do.  I successfully do it for gdb and C programs all the time.

Anyone had this issue and know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure pdb is supposed to look in the path; it takes a relative or absolute filename.  Does the same pdb command work differently in Emacs vs. a shell?

Comment: i think maybe my mistake is expecting it to behave like gdb

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're able to run your script outside of Emacs, but not
within, you probably
need
[exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).
This syncs up environment variables (like `PATH`) between your shell
and Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the realgud package since you are using python?

```
;;M-x load-library realgud python -m pdb myscript.py  
(package-install 'realgud) ;; python debugging in emacs
(defun sdev/init-realgud
  (interactive)
  (load-library "realgud"))  
(sdev/init-realgud 1)
```